# Qt call a class from a QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, class, call, qgraphicsitem

Well so I'm creating a Tower Defense game in Qt.
So my Tower is shouting and spawning a bullet class.
In this bullet class there is a polygon around it that allows me to detect if there's an enemy touching the bullet:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> colliding_items=collidingItems();
for(int i=0,n=colliding_items.size();i<n;i++){
    if(typeid(*(colliding_items[i]))==typeid(Enemy))
    {
     //<------------ HERE ?
     scene()->removeItem(this);
     delete this;
     return;
    }
}
```

I created a function in the header file `Enemy.h` called `receiveDamage(int damage)`:

```
void Enemy::reciveDamage(int damage){
    m_health -= damage;
    if(m_health <= 0){
       game->scene->removeItem(this);
       delete this;
       return;
    }
}
```

Content of `Ennemy.h`:

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QObject>
#include <QList> // list << element
#include <QPointF>

class Enemy: public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Enemy(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
    void rotateToPoint(QPointF p);
    void reciveDamage(int damage);
public slots:
    void move_forward();
private:
    QList<QPointF> points;
    QPointF dest;
    int point_index;
    int m_speed = 2;
    int m_health = 100;
};

#endif // ENEMY_H
```

But I don't know how to call it in my code up there, any ideas ?

Comment: Please give some more details and context (e.g the scope of your code snippet, and the definition of your enemy class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just `dynamic_cast` or `qobject_cast` the `QGraphicsItem` into a `Enemy` class and call `getDamage` on it.

If I suppose that the amount of damage is given by a method named `sendDamage`, the code could look like:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> colliding_items=collidingItems();
for(int i=0, n=colliding_items.size(); i<n; i++){
    if(typeid(*(colliding_items[i])) == typeid(Enemy))
    {
        Enemy* enemy = qobject_cast<Enemy*> (colliding_items[i]);
        if (enemy)
        {
            enemy->getDamage(this->sendDamage());
        }
        scene()->removeItem(this);
        delete this;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also: consider using `qgraphicsitem_cast` or `qobject_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`. No need to add RTTI stuff, when you can do it the qt way...

Comment: @Frodon `qgraphicsitem_cast` requires the implementation of [QGraphicsItem::type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#type), that's why I didn't suggested an edit right away.

Comment: @Dreamcooled Indeed I just read it from the doc. I'll edit again to be consistent.